# How to print an array list

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to print an array list but it can't print. Please help.

package com.company;

import java.util.ArrayList;

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        ArrayList<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();
        String harryPotter = new String();
        Student hermoineG = new Student("Hermoine", "Granger", 12);
        System.out.println(hermoineG.getFull());
        Student ronW = new Student("Ron","Weasley",12);
        System.out.println(ronW.getFull());
        Student dracoM = new Student("Draco","Malfoy", 11);
        System.out.println(dracoM.getFull());
        Student lunaL = new Student("Luna", "Lovegood", 9);
        System.out.println(lunaL.getFull());
        Student nevilleL = new Student("Neville", "Longbottom",8);
        System.out.println(nevilleL.getFull());
        Student cedricD = new Student("Cedric","Diggory",12);
        System.out.println(cedricD.getFull());
        Student georgeW = new Student("George", "Weasley",10);
        System.out.println(georgeW.getFull());
        Student padmaP = new Student("Padma", "Patil", 11);
        System.out.println(padmaP.getFull());
        Student fredW = new Student("Fred", "Weasley", 8);
        System.out.println(fredW.getFull());
        School.addStudents(School.students, harryPotter);
        System.out.println(hermoineG.getClass());
        students.add(hermoineG);
        System.out.println(students);

    }
}
```

Comment: Is this any language in particular?  Can you be more specific than "it can't print", like an error message or *something*?

Comment: `String harryPotter = new String();` seems irrelevant. Have you looked into using loops?

Comment: Does it compile? Where is `School.students` defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to use a loop:

```
for (Student student : students) {
    System.out.println(student.getFull());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you create your own class like Student you need to override the toString method in your Student class in order for it to print with System.out.println.  Add the following to your Student class:

```
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return  getFull();
    }
```

This will allow System.out.println(students); to correctly print the ArrayList.  As it stands you only have one student in the list though.

Note that the above will show the Student object as it is formatted in the "getFull" method.  You can change the formatting if needed.